# CSS multi-column snake pattern

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have a list of items like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
</div>

.container {
  column-count: 4;
}
```

Which gives me:

```
A  D  G  J
B  E  H  K
C  F  I  L
```

Is there a way to get (without changing the markup structure):

```
A  F  G  L
B  E  H  K
C  D  I  J
```

Where every even column goes bottom to top to mimic a snake pattern.

Comment: without changing the markup at all, then you can probably use css grid, but it would involve using nth-child selectors to select each item, and manually arrange each on the grid. It's a tedious method and won't work all that great if the number of these items are likely to change..

Comment: @Jasmine if the number of row will always be 3 then we don't need a lot of nth-child() : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598708/8620333

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}
.item { width: calc(100% / 4); }
.item:nth-child(1) { order: 0; }
.item:nth-child(2) { order: 5; }
.item:nth-child(3) { order: 9; }
.item:nth-child(4) { order: 10; }
.item:nth-child(5) { order: 6; }
.item:nth-child(6) { order: 2; }
.item:nth-child(7) { order: 3; }
.item:nth-child(8) { order: 7; }
.item:nth-child(9) { order: 11; }
.item:nth-child(10) { order: 12; }
.item:nth-child(11) { order: 8; }
.item:nth-child(12) { order: 4; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking about a more dynamic solution, I could have 200 items.

Comment: For that you need to alter the structure.