# How can I reverse flexbox direction on wrap to achieve "snake wrap"?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to find a way to have elements in a single container wrap to a new line going the opposite direction of the previous line, like a snake curving back on itself. I have not been able to achieve this result with flexbox and any combination of flex-direction and flex-wrap properties.

Image comparison of flexbox result vs desired result:

[image: Image comparison of flexbox result vs desired result]

And here is a snippet showing the flexbox result vs desired result (faked):

```css
body {
  font: 400 14px 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.title:first-child {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}

.flex-container, .fake-container, .fake-row {
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container {
  flex-flow: row wrap; /* any combination of row/reverse & wrap/reverse */
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: purple;
  width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.fake-container {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.fake-row {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100px;
}

.fake-row:nth-child(2) {
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Flexbox result:</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>

<div class="title">Desired result (faked):</div>
<div class="fake-container">
  <div class="fake-row">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fake-row">
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As much as I would love to find a pure CSS solution to achieve this "snake wrap", I am starting to doubt its possibility. I'm sure a javascript solution could be employed, but am unsure how to proceed in creating one without making things overly-complicated.

Is there any simple solution out there? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't do that with flexbox. Flexbox is just one dimensional. You can wrap to the next line, but it will be the same as the one above.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Vern, I don't know the real answer but try this via [css grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A CSS grid solution [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598708/8620333) that works with a fixed number of elements per row (aka fixed number of columns).

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(5,1fr); /*define the number of column*/
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this is important to fill all the space*/
  grid-gap:20px;
  padding:10px;
}

.item {
  background: purple;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(10n + 6)  {grid-column:5}
.item:nth-child(10n + 7)  {grid-column:4}
.item:nth-child(10n + 8)  {grid-column:3}
.item:nth-child(10n + 9)  {grid-column:2}
/*.item:nth-child(10n + 10) {grid-column:1} not needed*/
/* For N = number of columns 
  .item:nth-child((2xN)n + (N+1)) { grid-column:N; }
  .item:nth-child((2xN)n + (N+2)) { grid-column:(N-1); }
  ....
  .item:nth-child((2xN)n + (2xN)) { grid-column:1; }

*/

.item:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
body {
  font: 400 14px 'Arial', sans-serif;
  counter-reset:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If you want a generic solution here is one using JS and flexbox. The trick is to set the `order` property based on the row position of each item. I will rely on [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49046973/8620333) to do most of the calculation in order to find the number of rows/columns:

```js
//total number of element
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var n_t = elems.length;
//width of an element
var w = parseInt(document.querySelector('.item').offsetWidth);
//full width of element with margin
var m = document.querySelector('.item').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.item'));
w = w + parseInt(m.marginLeft) + parseInt(m.marginRight);
//width of container
var w_c = parseInt(document.querySelector('.flex-container').offsetWidth);
//padding of container
var c = document.querySelector('.flex-container').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.flex-container'));
var p_c = parseInt(c.paddingLeft) + parseInt(c.paddingRight);


var adjust = function(){
   //only the width of container will change
   w_c = parseInt(document.querySelector('.flex-container').offsetWidth);
   //Number of columns
   nb = Math.min(parseInt((w_c - p_c) / w),n_t);
   //Number of rows
   nc = Math.ceil(n_t/nb);
   for(var j = 0;j<nb;j++) {
     for(var i = 0;i<nc;i++) {
       if(j + i*nb >= n_t) /* we exit if we reach the number of elements*/
        break
       if(i%2!=1) 
         elems[j + i*nb].style.order=j + i*nb; /* normal flow */
       else
         elems[j + i*nb].style.order=(nb - j) + i*nb; /* opposite flow */
     }
    }
}

adjust()
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){adjust()})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  background: purple;
  height: 80px;
  width:80px;
  margin:10px;
  line-height: 80px;
  grid-gap:20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}


.item:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
body {
  font: 400 14px 'Arial', sans-serif;
  counter-reset:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

There is a little issue with the last line in some cases when it's not full of item. You can rectify this by adding some margin to the last element

```js
//total number of element
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var n_t = elems.length;
//width of an element
var w = parseInt(document.querySelector('.item').offsetWidth);
//full width of element with margin
var m = document.querySelector('.item').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.item'));
w = w + parseInt(m.marginLeft) + parseInt(m.marginRight);
//width of container
var w_c = parseInt(document.querySelector('.flex-container').offsetWidth);
//padding of container
var c = document.querySelector('.flex-container').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.flex-container'));
var p_c = parseInt(c.paddingLeft) + parseInt(c.paddingRight);


var adjust = function(){
   //only the width of container will change
   w_c = parseInt(document.querySelector('.flex-container').offsetWidth);
   //Number of columns
   nb = Math.min(parseInt((w_c - p_c) / w),n_t);
   //Number of rows
   nc = Math.ceil(n_t/nb);
   for(var j = 0;j<nb;j++) {
     for(var i = 0;i<nc;i++) {
       if(j + i*nb >= n_t) /* we exit if we reach the number of elements*/
        break
       elems[j + i*nb].style.marginLeft='10px'; /*we rest the margin*/
       if(i%2!=1) 
         elems[j + i*nb].style.order=j + i*nb; /* normal flow */
       else {
         elems[j + i*nb].style.order=(nb - j) + i*nb; /* opposite flow */
         /*margin fix*/
         if(i == (nc - 1) && (j + i*nb == (n_t - 1)) && j<(nb-1)) {
            elems[j + i*nb].style.marginLeft=((nb*nc - n_t)*w + 10) + 'px';
         }
       }
     }
    }
}

adjust()
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){adjust()})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  background: purple;
  height: 80px;
  width:80px;
  margin:10px;
  line-height: 80px;
  grid-gap:20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}


.item:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
body {
  font: 400 14px 'Arial', sans-serif;
  counter-reset:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

You can easily switch to the other direction by simply changing `if(i%2!=1)` to `if(i%2!=0)`

```js
//total number of element
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var n_t = elems.length;
//width of an element
var w = parseInt(document.querySelector('.item').offsetWidth);
//full width of element with margin
var m = document.querySelector('.item').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.item'));
w = w + parseInt(m.marginLeft) + parseInt(m.marginRight);
//width of container
var w_c = parseInt(document.querySelector('.flex-container').offsetWidth);
//padding of container
var c = document.querySelector('.flex-container').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.flex-container'));
var p_c = parseInt(c.paddingLeft) + parseInt(c.paddingRight);


var adjust = function(){
   //only the width of container will change
   w_c = parseInt(document.querySelector('.flex-container').offsetWidth);
   //Number of columns
   nb = Math.min(parseInt((w_c - p_c) / w),n_t);
   //Number of rows
   nc = Math.ceil(n_t/nb);
   for(var j = 0;j<nb;j++) {
     for(var i = 0;i<nc;i++) {
       if(j + i*nb >= n_t) /* we exit if we reach the number of elements*/
        break
       elems[j + i*nb].style.marginLeft='10px'; /*we rest the margin*/
       if(i%2!=0) 
         elems[j + i*nb].style.order=j + i*nb; /* normal flow */
       else {
         elems[j + i*nb].style.order=(nb - j) + i*nb; /* opposite flow */
         /*margin fix*/
         if(i == (nc - 1) && (j + i*nb == (n_t - 1)) && j<(nb-1)) {
            elems[j + i*nb].style.marginLeft=((nb*nc - n_t)*w + 10) + 'px';
         }
       }
     }
    }
}

adjust()
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){adjust()})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  background: purple;
  height: 80px;
  width:80px;
  margin:10px;
  line-height: 80px;
  grid-gap:20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}


.item:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
body {
  font: 400 14px 'Arial', sans-serif;
  counter-reset:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really clever and elegant solution. I was unaware of CSS grids, and definitely want to learn more about them now. Unfortunately, in my case, since I'm wrapping based on the width of the elements and the width of the screen, I can't use fixed columns. Thanks for this idea nonetheless!

Comment: @Vern added a JS solution, will update with more details

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! Gonna take me a bit to read through the JS and try to understand everything that's going on here, but it works perfectly and meets all the requirements. Since I doubt there's a true CSS-only solution out there (yet), I'm marking this the accepted answer. Thank you so much!