# CSS Grid Alternating Content in Divs

Tags: css, css-grid

I have these 6 divs aligned in a CSS grid which I would want divs to switch places every other row. which the wrapper grid-template would need to be switched every other row.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr  var(--block-width);
}
```

```
<div class=wrapper>
 <div>#1 </div>
 <div>#2 </div>
 <div>#3 </div>
 <div>#4 </div>
 <div>#5 </div>
 <div>#6 </div>
</div>
```

Heres what I would the layout to display.
[image]

Comment: You're looking for a snake-line pattern. See the duplicate posts.

Comment: here is another example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59481712/8620333