# How to order an array in a specific way with bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In my angular 8 project I want to order an array in that way:

```
1   4   7   10
2   5   8   11
3   6   9   12
```

This list comes from GET call so I don't know how many items are there, and it needs to be responsive as much as possible.
I am using Bootstrap 4.x and I am trying to achieve that with `flex-direction` property but I am missing something.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58598575/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution form me is to use `column-count: 3`, and for the responsiveness I update the column count based on the screen size in an easy way.

With column count I don't have to specify height or other css, just css 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure bootstrap's grid / flex utility classes alone will give you a full solution for your requirement since you'll inevitably have to supply a max height for a container on your own in some way to invoke the proper wrapping of the child elements you're repeating.

So here's a quick approach to do the same, if you want we could translate some of it to the utility classes and I guess just slap an adhoc way to constrict the container and invoke wrapping to get the same result and have it be more boostrap'ish...

```css
.container {
  height: 11rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>* {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.container div {
  height: 1rem;
  max-height: 1rem;
  border: lightgray 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- These would be the divs you repeat with your xhr -->
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but what about responsiveness? with bootstrap I have all my columns responsive, so is it possible in this case to have something like `col-sm-4 col-md-3`?

Comment: You could make it to use some of the [sizing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/) or depending on how you're using bootstrap if you have their scss directly in your build pipeline you could add your own sizing directly to their variables and have custom stuff produced with the utility classes to work with. Or you could always add your own [media queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) to cover the responsiveness also.