# Fixed number of rows, if more content comes it should go to next column using css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a situation where number of rows should be 3 and if there are more items it should go to next column. That is each column should only have three items

I did like this

```
.sub-options-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
```

But this will only go up to 3 columns, but I wanted it to add dynamically more columns depending on more items added, but each column should only have three rows

I am able to achieve this if I wanted fixed columns and dynamically adding rows by simply only defining columns as shown

```
.sub-options-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

I cant find a solution in stackoverflow, sorry if this is asked

Comment: almost a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598575/grid-auto-flow-in-snake-lines/58598708#58598708 .. check the first snippet and stop on the grid definition (no need the nth-chid tricks)

Comment: `grid-auto-columns:20px;
  grid-auto-flow:column dense;` is this that makes the difference?

Comment: yes and especially the `grid-auto-flow:column dense;` (you can remove `dense` in your case)